# How to create a new cache region in SAP Commerce (hybris)

Tags: caching, ehcache, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to create a new region for a specific set of models. I've followed the [documentation about RegionCache](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8c392bd686691014ae1bf4af383a81d5.html) but it doesn't work.

Here is the configuration :

```
<alias name="defaultTestCacheRegion" alias="testCacheRegion"/>
<bean name="defaultTestCacheRegion" class="de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="testCacheRegion" />
    <constructor-arg name="maxEntries" value="${regioncache.testcacheregion.maxentries}" />
    <constructor-arg name="evictionPolicy" value="${regioncache.testcacheregion.evictionpolicy}" />
    <constructor-arg name="statsEnabled" value="${regioncache.stats.enabled}" />
    <constructor-arg name="exclusiveComputation" value="${regioncache.exclusivecomputation}" />
    <property name="handledTypes">
        <array>
            <value>25049</value>
            <value>25050</value>
            <value>25051</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="testCacheRegionRegistrar" class="de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.CacheRegionRegistrar" c:region-ref="testCacheRegion" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually miss how the Spring context works in hybris. Since it has to be accessible from all application contexts it has to be set on global level.

> All application contexts have as the parent the global application context.

The cache region bean  has to be defined in a "global" spring file. In hybris it's done by setting this property. (`my_cache.xml` has to be in `resources` in `project_name`)

```
<project_name>.global-context=my_cache.xml
```